# Changing Ownership of a directory in OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew, chown

I've installed homebrew, and am trying to change the write permissisons for the /usr/local/include directory.

When I run 'brew doctor', I get this error message:

> Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable. Even if this
>   directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other software may
>   change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the "InstantOn"
>   component of Airfoil are known to do this.
>
> You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
>   back to your user account.

I tried doing that with chown, but I'm pretty new at this and don't think I was running it correctly. I ran:

```
chown myusername /usr/local/include
```

I didn't get any error message, but when I run brew doctor it says I still lack permission to write to /usr/local/include.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

I'm getting an "operation not permitted" error.

`cd /usr`

`chown myusername local`

chown: local: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my system, `/usr/local` is owned by `root:admin` and is `rwxrwxr-x`. My user is a member of the `admin` group, thus has write permissions. I haven't messed with ownership and permissions there, and my Homebrew installation is not complaining, so I assume my setup fits its requirements.

Check the ownership of your `/usr/local`; if it is owned by group `admin`, check if your non-adminsitrator account is a member of that group.

Comment: My username is an admin. /usr/local was owned by root:wheel. Not sure what that is. 

I used the -R flag and sudo to give me username write permission on all directories in /usr/local. For some reason it wouldn't accept 'admin' as an argument when I tried that.

Comment: Hi Graeme. I experienced exact same error (OS X Mavericks). Perhaps this will work for you as well: `sudo chown \`whoami\` \`brew --prefix\` && brew doctor`. Hope this helps! (Note: `echo \`whoami\`` >> yourusername and `echo \`brew --prefix\`` >> /usr/local)

Answer (score 24):

Simple solution that worked for me:

1. click on your background to go to finder
2. click on go and go to folder /usr
3. right click on local and do get info
4. unlock the lock at the bottom
5. click + sign and add your user to the list and give read/write privileges
6. click on the gear sign at the bottom and choose apply to enclosed items to recurse under that directory and assign privileges too all directories beneath it.

type `brew doctor` from command prompt to test. My result:

> Your system is ready to brew.

Comment: I love this because it's not *changing* what's already there, just adding in the read/write permissions your user needs.

Comment: I'm unable to add user, getting error: ```The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission.```

Comment: Your answer saved a lot of time. Thank you!

Comment: Changing the ownership of /usr is extremely dangerous.  Anything you run (on purpose or otherwise) now has a chance of changing critical system files without asking for elevated privileges.  Homebrew for Intel Macs only needs /usr/local/ perms changes which is at least slightly better.

Answer (score 5):

### Be careful with the change of ownership

Do not try to change ownership for `/usr/` or recursively for `/usr/local/`
**if you are not getting the same error posted in the original question.**
You could screw up your system or weakness its security.

Some users can receive with homebrew permission errors that could be solved without changing the ownership of the whole `/usr/` or `/usr/local/` directories.

According to my experience, in most cases, it is just enough to restore the ownership for `/usr/local/Cellar`:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER" /usr/local/Cellar/
```

Alternatively, if you have a not standard installation

```
sudo chown -R "$USER" "$(brew --prefix)/Cellar"
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use: `sudo chown username folder`

Comment: Please explain why the OP should do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use command `ls -l`. With this command you will see list of files in current directory with some useful information, like who is owner of this file. So you will see if `chown` worked out. I believe that `chown` is a right command for changing ownership.

Comment: I'm getting an "operation not permitted" error.

`cd /usr`
`chown myusername local`

chown: local: Operation not permitted

Comment: in that case i think you should look, if you are administrator of the computer, because ls -l is pretty basic command, and you don`t need root permissions for it.

Comment: sorry, my comment wasn't clear. I can do ls -l. It was when I ran chown that I got the permission denied error.

I just ran it with sudo, that did it. I managed to give permission to my user. I wonder if I gave *too* much permission though. I used the -R flag on local, so now my username has permission for all directories within /usr/local. 

Is there a good place to start to get a deeper understanding of unix directory permissions and security? I'm only at the google --> find answer --> copy paste stage, which could be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly this problem has just started occuring on my MacBook.

The owner of /usr/local is:

```
drwxr-xr-x   24 root  wheel    768 Apr  9 17:25 local
```

I am unable to change the permissions and add myself via Finder - I get a "you don't have the necessary permission" error.

Is this maybe due to security changes in mac os? (I have 10.13.6)